Radius of convergence of power series.
Given the following power series,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{z^{3^{n}}-z^{2\cdot3^n}}{n}
$$
I have to prove that it has radius of convergence: $R=1$.
I have tried putting the expression in the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n(z-a)^n
$$
so as to apply the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem to directly compute the value of $R$ with the expression:
$$
R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}}
$$
or using:
$$
R=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|
$$
However, I don't know how to express the series in that form, and I can't think of any other way to proceed with the problem. If someone has any clues on how to, it would be really appreciated.

What does the standard ratio test tell you?

I've tried using it but I can't seem to know how to compute the limit. I know that if the limit is greater than one, the series is divergent, and if it's less than one, it's convergent.

One approach is to first write it as a standard power series.
Let $T=\{ 3^k | k \in \mathbb{N} \}$, then if $f(z)=\sum_n {1 \over n} z^{3^n} = \sum_n a_n z^n$ we see that
$a_n = \begin{cases} {1 \over \log_3n}, & n \in T\\
0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.
Hence $\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_{n \in T} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{{1 \over \log_3 n}} = \limsup_k \sqrt[3^k]{1 \over k} = 1$, and so the ROC of $f$'s power series is $1$.
Since $|z| <1$ iff $|z^2| < 1$, we see that the ROC of $z \mapsto f(z^2)$ is also $1$.
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3^{n}}-z^{2\cdot3^n}}{n} = f(z)-f(z^2)$, we obtains the desired result.
As @KritikerderElche noted, this answer is incomplete, it just demonstrates that the ROC is $ \ge 1$.
Let $g(z)= f(z)-f(z^2)$ and
note that $\operatorname{re} g(ri) = \sum_n { (r^2)^{3^n} \over n}$ and we see that $\lim_{r \uparrow 1} \operatorname{re} g(ri) \ge \sum_{n=1}^N {1 \over n}$ for all $N$, hence the ROC is at most one.

You prove that the radius of convergence $R$ is at least $1$ because it is the difference of two power series with radius of convergence $1$. But why can't it be bigger? For example, the difference of twice the same power series is $0$ which has $R = \infty$.

@KritikerderElche Good catch, I added an explanation to the answer.

Why the downvote???

I did not downvote ... on the contrary, I upvoted after your edit.

@KritikerderElche thanks - my comment was not aimed at you.
